# Azure Notebook won't run any python

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-cosmosdb, azureportal, azure-notebooks

I created a new Azure Notebook under a Cosmos DB resource but all python code goes to "busy" and won't complete. I'm trying with the very simple

```
print "test"
```

It just says `python3 | busy` as the status. I've tried interrupting, halting, and restarting the kernel to no avail. Even the sample notebooks won't run the python snippets.

[image: Azure notebook not running simple python]

Comment: I tried in another browser and the first message I saw was: "Cannot launch kernelspec: "python" is not supported by the notebook server. Found kernel with similar name: python3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I can't run python Notebook yesterday as well and get the same message with you. I think it is a bug. And now It can be run.

[image]